# Can an CakePHP MVC controller return an Image?

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible for cakephp controller to return an Image, basically need this for 
captcha image generation. I tried doing it from /webroot/files/captcha_gen.php and saving the 
code in session using .. $_SESSION["rand_code"], but for some reason, the controller
doesnt show it in the list of session variables ..

Answer (score 6):

yes it is, of course

you need to set the right headers (using cake2's response class)
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse

then you can just print out the image and it will just be a normal image for the browser:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->type('jpg');
$this->response->body($imageContent);
```